# Google Apps Script - copy a formula from one cell to another incrementing A1 notation in new cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When, in a google sheet, you click on a cell and in the bottom corner of the cell, drag the blue icon to the next cell, the formula goes with it and increments the A1 notation appropriately. `getFormula()` and `setFormula()` don't do this. Anyone know the function or steps to accomplish this?

```
function increment() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

  //Can this be used to increment A1 notation when setting a formula in another cell?
 // var cellNotation = sheet.getRange(1,1).getA1Notation();

 sheet.getRange(1,2).setFormula("=G11 + (F12*(1 +$C$3) )");

}
```

Comment: What is the expected output and what is the current output?

Comment: The formula takes a number in cell G11 and adds it to a number in F12 times the product in parenthesis which is a decimal.

Comment: Sum in parenthesis multiplied by F12

Comment: I get that, but where is this formula and where do you want to drag it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [setFormulaR1C1(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulaR1C1(String)) which updates the formula for the given range:

```
function increment() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var formula = sheet.getRange(1,1).getFormulaR1C1();
  sheet.getRange(1,2).setFormulaR1C1(formula);
}
```

**Be careful:**

- The `formula` argument in `setFormulaR1C1` needs to be in `R1C1` notation.
- For example, the formula: `=G11 + (F12*(1 +$C$3) )` is written in `R1C1` notation as

  `=R[10]C[6] + (R[11]C[5]*(1 +R3C3) )`
- You don't need to construct the `R1C1` notation manually. You can use [getFormulaR1C1()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulaR1C1()) (like the code I provided) to get the `R1C1` notation of a cell.
- [getFormulaR1C1()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulaR1C1()) returns `null` if there is no formula in the selected range.

Comment: Thank you Marios - I will give it a try.

Comment: It worked well! Thank you for clarifying that for me.